# CMake ignoring CMAKE_MODULE_PATH

Tags: cmake, include

I'm having trouble getting CMake's `include()` statement to recognize `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. I'm hoping to do something like this:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
include(Foo.cmake)
```

with this style of directory tree:

```
.
├── cmake
│   └── Foo.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
```

However, I get the error:

```
  include could not find load file:

    Foo.cmake
```

Based on the docs for [`include()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/include.html#command:include) and [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_MODULE_PATH), I thought that this should be possible.

If I keep the same tree but modify the `include`, it loads fine:

```
include(cmake/Foo.cmake)
```

Am I mistaken or doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: @Tsyarev thanks very much! Your second suggestion worked - searching for `Foo` instead of `Foo.cmake`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be a **module** name - **without** `.cmake` extension - for apply `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable when search the file with `include` command:

```
# This searches a *module* and uses 'CMAKE_MODULE_PATH' variable
include(Foo)
# This searches a *file* and doesn't use 'CMAKE_MODULE_PATH' variable
include(Foo.cmake)
```

---

The signature of `include` function

> include(<file|module> [OPTIONAL] [RESULT_VARIABLE ]
>                         [NO_POLICY_SCOPE])

means that its first argument could be either a **file** or a **module**.

And `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable is applied only when search a **module**:

> If a module is specified instead of a file, the file with name `<modulename>.cmake` is searched first in `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, then in the CMake module directory.

The name of the *file* - `<modulename>.cmake` - suggests that *module* name shouldn't have `.cmake` suffix.